# How to prevent a DOS attack with to many servlet sessions?

Tags: servlets, jetty, out-of-memory, denial-of-service

I have write a small test case which request the same URL in a loop without resending cookies. After a few minutes my Jetty server crash with an OutOfMemoryError. The cause is that every request produce a new session.

Are there any features of the Jetty server or the servlet API to prevent such attacks?

Comment: That's the responsibility of the loadbalancer/proxy, not webserver/servlet.

Comment: @BalusC There is no load balancer or proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider one of the following techniques:

- Don't use an in-memory Session management technique. (Use a database)
- Set the Session expiration / timeout lower
- Setup a [`DoSFilter`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/dos-filter.html) to manage it
- Setup a [`QoSFilter`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html) to mitigate the behavior a bit better.

Comment: This seems not very usable answer. Moving the session in the database does not change any. Setting a session timeout to few seconds will be fatal. The QoSFilter does not help to prevent any in this case. QoS is another problem. The DoS filter can be help but what are useful settings? Do you use it self?

Comment: Have used every one of those techniques on different servers for different use cases, and different companies.  Sometimes a single technique is appropriate, sometimes more than one is.  They do help, the effectiveness of each is listed in same order in my answer.